# Mule application is not starting

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

Hello recently i have updated my jks and nothing else, and my application is not starting

Any ideas?

```
WARN org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain - GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution

2021-12-22 12:16:53,657 [app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT].app2-httpListenerConfig

2021-12-22 13:04:30,722 [[app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT].app2-httpListenerConfig.worker.03] WARN org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain - GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

at org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.PSSSigner.generateSignature(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar:1.56.0]

at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.PSSSignatureSpi.engineSign(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar:1.56.0]

at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1382) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:698) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.ECDHServerKeyExchange$ECDHServerKeyExchangeMessage.<init>(ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:177) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.ECDHServerKeyExchange$ECDHServerKeyExchangeProducer.produce(ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:495) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T12ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1020) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:727) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:693) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:981) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:968) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:915) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLUtils.executeDelegatedTask(SSLUtils.java:274) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:709) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLFilter.java:332) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:623) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:335) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.MuleSslFilter.handleRead(MuleSslFilter.java:45) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0-20210217.jar:3.9.0-20210217]

at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyAddressDelegateFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyAddressDelegateFilter.java:59) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0-20210217.jar:3.9.0-20210217]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:119) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0-20210217.jar:3.9.0-20210217]

at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:31) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0-20210217.jar:3.9.0-20210217]

at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:142) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0-20210217.jar:3.9.0-20210217]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_312]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_312]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_312]

2021-12-22 13:04:30,901 [[app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT].app2-httpListenerConfig.worker.01] WARN org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain - GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

at org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.PSSSigner.generateSignature(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar:1.56.0]

at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.PSSSignatureSpi.engineSign(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar:1.56.0]

at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1382) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:698) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.ECDHServerKeyExchange$ECDHServerKeyExchangeMessage.<init>(ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:177) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.ECDHServerKeyExchange$ECDHServerKeyExchangeProducer.produce(ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:495) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T12ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1020) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:727) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:693) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:981) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:968) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:915) ~[?:1.8.0_312]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLUtils.executeDelegatedTask(SSLUtils.java:274) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:709) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLFilter.java:332) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:623) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:335) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.MuleSslFilter.handleRead(MuleSslFilter.java:45) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0-20210217.jar:3.9.0-20210217]

at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyAddressDelegateFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyAddressDelegateFilter.java:59) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0-20210217.jar:3.9.0-20210217]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]

at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:119) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0-20210217.jar:3.9.0-20210217]

at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:31) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0-20210217.jar:3.9.0-20210217]

at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:142) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0-20210217.jar:3.9.0-20210217]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_312]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_312]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_312]
```

And more log :

```
httpListenerConfig.worker.01] ERROR org.mule.module.apikit.MappingExceptionListener - 

********************************************************************************

Message        : /

Element        : /app2-user-sysapi-main/processors/6/1/1 @ app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:app2-user-sysapi.xml:38 (APIkit Router)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Exception stack is:

/ (org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException)

 org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractConfiguration$2.load(AbstractConfiguration.java:178)

 org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractConfiguration$2.load(AbstractConfiguration.java:169)

 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)

 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2319)

 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2282)

 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2197)

 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)

 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941)

 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824)

 org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractRouter.processRouterRequest(AbstractRouter.java:177)

 (109 more...)

 

 (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)

********************************************************************************
```

After trying to upload jks and re-deployed it get's problem. Even i revert with old jks didn't get starting the application...What can be the problem?

Tried to run from new runtime 3.9.0 version but still no luck on this and not working at all.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you running the Enterprise Edition or the Community Edition? Are you deploying using Runtime Manager? Did you try with a newer release than 3.9.0 (latest Mule 3 is Mule 3.9.5)? The logs snippets lack context to be sure if they are related to the error. You said the application did not deploy but the APIKit error seems to imply it deployed. The Grizzly message is a warning, not an error. It is difficult to understand if they are related to your issue or indicate something different. Are these messages from mule_ee.log, app log, mule_agent.log?

Comment: I'm running CE

I'm deploying from gitlab and my scripts are working under 3.9.0 at the moment. Yes it got's deployed now. 

The logs are from application log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Mule runtime CE 3.9.5, no more problems.

Thanks!